# Как использовать Django ORM не в Django проекте, а в обычном питоновском файле

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

Я хочу использовать Django ORM для создания бд в telegram боте. Знаю, есть SQLAlchermy, но я хотел бы использовать Django ORM, так как он роднее.
Первый вопрос: Возможно ли использовать Django ORM вне django проектов, а в обычном питоновском файле.
Второй вопрос: Если это возможно, то как это реализовать?

Comment: Запускайте бота через management-команду Django, и таким образом будет полный доступ к Django. Только будут нюансы с [соединениями к БД](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32589) и возможно с [асинхронщиной](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/async/)